# touchpad not showing and gives no errors

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx, touchpad

So, I've finally made a body using **Physics Body Editor** and **Box2D** in **libGDX**. Now I would love to create a classy **touchpad** using **libGDX**. Basically, I did it like the following:

```
// Touchpad
private Touchpad touchpad;
private Touchpad.TouchpadStyle touchpadStyle;
private Skin touchpadSkin;
private Drawable touchBackground;
private Drawable touchKnob;
```

and that is what i wrote in the `create()` method:

```
// Touchpad initialisation
    touchpadSkin = new Skin();
    touchpadSkin.add("touchBackground", new Texture("touchBackground.png"));
    touchpadSkin.add("touchKnob", new Texture("touchKnob.png"));

    touchpadStyle = new Touchpad.TouchpadStyle();

    touchBackground = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchBackground");
    touchKnob = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchKnob");

    touchpadStyle.background = touchBackground;
    touchpadStyle.knob = touchKnob;

    touchpad = new Touchpad(10, touchpadStyle);
    touchpad.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.addActor(touchpad);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

But, as I tested it, I discovered that no touchpad was ever rendered. Maybe that is all about the camera, so there:

- camera declaration:

  `private OrthographicCamera camera;`
- camera viewport declaration:

  `private static final float VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 1920;`
- camera in `create ()` method:

  `camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_WIDTH*h/w);
  camera.position.set(0, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0);
  camera.update();`

I do not know, is that all the information the one would need to answer my question, so just to be clear, there is [the whole class](http://pastie.org/9949944)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've made a silly mistake - forgot to put the **stage** stuff in the `render()` method ))):

```
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.draw();
```